# Some Profiles on takser doesn't work

Tags: tasker

I have 2 simple Tasker profiles. The notification says "No active profiles", but the first task (Keyboard Out) doesn't work. The second task (Call Outgoing) works well.

Root access has been granted, Accessibility is enabled and Administrator is active.

What could the problem be ?

Galaxy S5 With stock Android Marshmallow..

[image: 1st Task]
[image: 2nd Task]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you export and share the Keyboard Profile with us?

Comment: @bmdixon http://wikisend.com/download/575206/Keyboard_Out.prf.xml

Answer (score 0):

There must be a missing action which links your Profile state to the Task,

also check if in your created Task, all parameters are accessible to the device,

(for example you forgot to choose the app that will be effected that trigger even - 
say you want keyboard out ttigger when you open Dictionary app, and you forget to include all parameters to enable that dictionary app or it may be that it no longer exist in the phone.

Comment: Would mind showing the rest of the Task so we can help you diagnose that error